# how to create object using package name

Tags: java, object

```
Object obj = getInstance("com.util.Classname");

obj.show();
```

`show()` is the method in class Classname
this is the package com.util.Classname...

now they gave me only this and told me to create a object of that Classname class and to call that show() method.

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You already did that.

Comment: `((com.util.Classname) obj).show();`

Comment: Are _they_ talking to you too?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to use String as your class name and method name than you can use reflection for get class object and for invoke any particular method

```
    // Get the object
    Object obj = Class.forName("com.util.Classname").newInstance();
    // Get method using reflection.
    Method showMethod = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("show");
    // invoke the method
    showMethod.invoke(obj);
```

Comment: It is about method parameters, show method does not have any parameter so it is null.

Comment: That's a varargs type. You shouldn't pass anything if there are no parameters.. It should just be `getDeclaredMethod("toString");`

Comment: @Codebender .. Yes you are right. changing the answer accordingly